# SSRS Matrix using a Dynamic Column Header

Tags: sql-server, matrix, dynamic, reporting-services

I have an SSRS Report with a Matrix that looks like this:

[image]

and will return this:

[image]

This Matrix currently give me exact pivot and values I need, but I need the column headers to be something different. In the same table I get the [Key] column from, I have another column called [ColumnHeader] that I would like to display instead.
However the pivot will not work if I use the value of [ColumnHeader], hence why I only want to display the value but actually pivot using the [Key] value.

The end result will display like this:

[image]

and return this:

[image]

But it will still display the same information from the first picture.
Please note that [Key] and [ColumnName] are not the same value. [Key] is able to return the values I want while [ColumnName] are names of the columns I need to display.

Comment: I think a small sample of your dataset's data (and the underlying tables) and expected output based on that sample would help. From what you have said I don't see why you can't just set your column group to use the columnheader value instead of key, it should result in the same thing I would have thought.There might be a good reason why you can't do this but it's not obvious from your question.

Comment: Unfortunately the data I have for this is sensitive and I can't post it. In case it wasn't clear the Key and ColumnHeader are not the same value. The Key value is what return my value. The ColumnHeader is just what I want to display on my report, and does not return and sort of value.

Comment: I still need to see Sample data as it is in the underlying tables to understand the issue. Just fake something, as long as its structure matches your real data it will be fine.

Comment: already added some.

Comment: UNDERLYING TABLES not the dataset

Comment: Can you pivot on Key and show ColumnHeader in the table? From what it sounds like you probably don’t have a 1-1 match between Key and ColumnHeader.